# Relative URL for RouteProvider in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, relative-path, angularjs-routing

I have a website that will likely be placed within a directory in IIS.  When I am running the application on my computer through IISExpress, the routes are relative to the base URL, so I can just define my routes as follows:

```
$routeProvider.when("/home", {
    controller: "homeController",
    templateUrl: "/app/layout/myView.html"
});
```

This gives me the following URL:
http://localhost:60847/#/home

When I put publish this site to our server, I have the URL:
http://dev.mysite.com/MyApp/#/home

However, I keep getting an error "Failed to load template: /app/layout/myView.html".  When I look at Fiddler, I can see that it is trying to pull in the template from http://dev.mysite.com/app/layout/myView.html instead of from http://dev.mysite.com/MyApp/app/layout/myView.html.  I have tried rewriting the templateUrl as ../app/layout/myView.html, as ~/app/layout/myView.html, and as ../../app/layout/myView.html.  No matter what I do, I still end up trying to pull it from the parent folder instead of from MyApp.  I have also tried setting a web.config setting and using that to put a prefix on the templateUrl, but it doesn't seem to want to run that code prior to loading the template.  Finally, I have tried setting up a function for the templateUrl, but the way I have that stored in the web.config file creates timing issues with pulling the information.

It seems as if this must be a common issue that I am making overly complicated.  Is there a way to make this a relative URL?

Comment: If I understood your problem correctly you want to navigate to home picking MyApp/app/layout/myView.html. 
First of all you don't need /app/layout/myView.html, app/layout/myView.html is correct.
Second, if your 'MyApp' folder contains app try templateUrl: "MyApp/app/layout/myView.html" or templateUrl: "../app/layout/myView.html"

Comment: The problem is that I am not going to know in advance what 'MyApp' is called, so I would have to find out and then change all my code once this is in production.  I was looking for a way to put it in one location and not have to recompile anything afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add to your HTML's head:

```
<base href="MyApp/" />
```

See [this documentation page](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) for more details.

Comment: Thanks!  I was able to set this programmatically from the setting in my web.config file.